# Is ./*/ portable?

Tags: shell, sh, posix, glob

I often use `./*/` in a for loop like

```
for d in ./*/; do
  : # do something with dirs
done
```

to match all non-hidden directories in current working directory, but I'm not really sure if this is a portable way to do that. I have bash, dash and ksh installed on my system and it works with all, but since [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_06) doesn't say anything about it (or it says implicitly, and I missed it) I think I can't rely on it. I also checked [POSIX bug reports](http://austingroupbugs.net/search.php?project_id=0&search=pathname+expansion&sticky_issues=off&sortby=last_updated&dir=DESC&hide_status_id=-2&FILTER_SEARCH_PLATFORM=), but to no avail, there's no mention of it there as well.

Is its behaviour implementation or filesystem dependent? Am I missing something here? How do I know if it's portable or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: YES

Long Answer:

The POSIX standard (from opengroup) states that */* will only match slashes in the expanded file name. Since Unix/Linux does not allow */* in the file name, I believe that this is a safe assumption on Unix/Linux systems.

From the bolded text below, it seems that even for systems that will allow */* in the file name, the POSIX standard require that */* will not be matched to such file.

On Windows, looks like */* is not allowed in the file name, but I'm not an expert on Windows.

From [Shell Programming Language § Patterns Used for Filename Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_03):

> The slash character in a pathname shall be explicitly matched by using one or more slashes in the pattern; it shall neither be matched by the asterisk or question-mark special characters nor by a bracket expression. Slashes in the pattern shall be identified before bracket expressions; thus, a **slash cannot be included in a pattern bracket expression used for filename expansion**. 
>   ...

**Additional Note - clarifying pathname:**

The *pathname* is defined in 4.13, with explicit reference to pathname with trailing slash in [General Concepts § Pathname Resolution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_13).

> A pathname that contains at least one non-<slash> character and that ends with one or more trailing <slash> characters shall not be resolved successfully unless the last pathname component before the trailing <slash> characters names an existing directory or a directory entry that is to be created for a directory immediately after the pathname is resolved. Interfaces using pathname resolution may specify additional constraints when a pathname that does not name an existing directory contains at least one non-<slash> character and contains one or more trailing <slash> characters.