# How to remove all subdirectories? (unix shell scripting)

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a directory called "cdrs-roaming". Everyday I receive one or more .zip files and unzip them with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.zip
do
    j=${i//\.zip/}
    mkdir $j
    cd $j
    unzip  ../$i
    cd -
done
```

Then I have for example:
"example1.zip" and "example1"; "example2.zip" and "example2"

I'm removing all zip files (in this case: "example1.zip" and "example2.zip") with this:

```
#! /bin/bash
find /dados/cdrs-roaming/*.zip -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
```

So I want to remove the directories (or folders - I really don't know the difference) "example1" and "example2". I've tried this:

```
#! /bin/bash
find /dados/cdrs-roaming/ -type d -mtime +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

But it also removes "cdrs-roaming". I've also tried to use:

```
find /cdrs-roaming/ -type d -mtime +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

But it returns: find: ‘/cdrs-roaming/’: No such file or directory

Any idea for doing this? I need to delete only the directories within "cdrs-roaming" but I can't remove anything else inside it (my .sh files are inside of it)

Comment: The only difference between a "directory" and a "folder" is that the former is traditional UNIX terminology and the latter is traditional Windows terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using bash, how about

```
rm -rf /dados/cdrs-roaming/*/
```

The final slash ensures that bash only expands the pattern to directories.

Comment: Thank you very much! This way I can remove all directories and subdirectories safely

Comment: 'Safely' is a relative term. I always feel a shudder, if I do a `rm -rf`.....

Comment: Not only bash, this should work in all POSIX shells. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58176457/is-portable

Answer (score 0):

Use `-mindepth 1` option:

```
find /dados/cdrs-roaming/ -mindepth 1 -type d -mtime +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks! You helped a lot. I've changed "-mtime +1" to "-mmin +1" and it worked. First time there wasn't any directory from 1 day